# Change password for a user in CakePHP 2.1

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm building a page where a user can change their password. They must fill two fields and both must match before it will be changed and then they will be redirected to their profile page on success.

So far I have built the following method:

```
public function changePassword()
{

    $user = $this->User->find('first', array( 
                'conditions' => array(
                    'User.id' => $this->Auth->user('id')) 
            ));

    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put'))
    {
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data))
        {
            $this->User->saveField('password', AuthComponent::password($this->request->data['User']['password2']));

            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your password has been changed!'));
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'profiles','action'=>'view','userName'=>$user['User']['username']));
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Whoops! Something went wrong... try again?'));
        }
    }

}
```

and this is the form:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(); ?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->input('id',array('type'=>'hidden')); ?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->input('password1',array('type'=>'text','label'=>array('text'=>'Enter your new password'))); ?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->input('password2',array('type'=>'text','label'=>array('text'=>'Confirm your new password'))); ?>

    <button type="submit">Save</button>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

So as you can see the plan is to take what it says in password2 and save it in the database password field using the security hashing. But what happens is it creates a new user instead but with blank data... What am I doing wrong here? And how do I compare the two password fields...

Comment: you can let a behavior take care of that: http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/ - or at least take some of the functionality provided to find a suitable solution for your own approach.

Comment: Why is my code creating a new user though?

Comment: For comparing to passwords fields.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185246/password-confirm-validation-cakephp/18017468#18017468

Answer (score 1):

most probable issue is that you somehow lose the id from the form back to the controller action.
without the id present in the data array cake assumes that it has to create an entry.

so debug your posted data and ensure that it is not missing or better assign the id manually prior to saving.

```
$this->request->data['User']['id'] = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
```

PS: from the look at your method your hidden "id" field stays always empty as the $user data is not passed down from the controller!

Comment: also use fieldList for whitelisting or better the security component to avoid any tempering with the form which would result in a security risk.

Answer (score 1):

public function recover()
    {

```
    if ($this->request->is('post') )
    {
        $this->loadModel('AclManagement.User');
        $passwords = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);

        $this->User->query("UPDATE users SET password = '".$passwords."' WHERE password_change = '".$this->request->data['User']['id']."' ");
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Password Saved Sucessfully'), 'success');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'login'));    
    }
    else
    {
        $this->set('resettoken', $_REQUEST['id']);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->request->data['User']['password2'] = AuthComponent::password($this->request->data['User']['password2']);

$this->User->save($this->request->data);
```

As your form submit with auth user `id` so, if you execute `save()` with request data, cake will simply update your record, instead of create due to `id` field(if any record exists against this `id`in the table). Above code just update the `password2` with the Hash password within the request data.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you specify the action edit in your form?

```
    echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'edit'));
```