# Password Confirm Validation CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have searched far and wide, tried every trick in the book, but I still can't get my CakePHP application to perform simple Password Confirm validation. I've tried creating a custom validation rule like this:

```
'passwordequal' => array('rule' => 'checkpasswords' , 'message' => 'Passwords Do Not Match')
```

Then defined 'checkpasswords' like this:

```
public function checkpasswords(){

    if(strcmp($this->data['User']['new_password'],$this->data['User']['confirm_password']) == 0 )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

'new_password' and 'confirm_password' are the password input fields. This didn't work. Then I tried one in which I hashed the 'confirm_password'. That didn't work either. I have other 'rules' as well that are not being validated, like 'notempty', which I believe is one of the standard CakePHP rules. Can anybody please help. I know this question has been asked a few times but none of those solutions have worked for me. CakePHP documentation hasn't helped much either.

Comment: Did you output those values to see if they are being read by your method correctly before the comparison?

Comment: can you show us an example of the `$this->data` input that's failing? you should show your whole model class code too.

Comment: You can find tips, code examples as well as a full working behavior for that here: http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/

Comment: @mark Your Password Behavior has helped me a lot. Everything is working perfectly now. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

two fields in view file

```
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->input('repass');
```

Model file

```
<?php
class Post extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
        'repass' => array(
            'equaltofield' => array(
            'rule' => array('equaltofield','password'),
            'message' => 'Require the same value to password.',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            )
        )
    );

function equaltofield($check,$otherfield)
    {
        //get name of field
        $fname = '';
        foreach ($check as $key => $value){
            $fname = $key;
            break;
        }
        return $this->data[$this->name][$otherfield] === $this->data[$this->name][$fname];
    } 
}?>
```

Comment: I didn't know that $this->data can be used in model.I thought it is deprecated in 2.x versions. Thanks for that.

Comment: When use `echo $this->Form->input('repass');`, your password **display plain text**. It is unacceptable. And better is use client side to validate first (javascript).

Comment: @DoNhuVy it can be easily fixed using `array('type' => 'password')` as a param when rendering the field in the view file. What is unacceptable is rely only in client side to make this kind of validation. You should always expect that some users will disable JavaScript to 'hack' your system.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your model is not loading correctly and using a dynamically generated model.

Comparing passwords in 2.x is nothing more than comparing any two fields as cake no longer hashes the pw automatically.

Can you confirm your validation method is being run, seems like its not especially if simple things like `notEmpty` is not working.